# Import HTML Drupal module with custom XSL template

Tags: html, xslt, drupal

I have a requirement to import a html website to Drupal and I have decided to using [Import HTML](https://drupal.org/project/import_html) module to do it.

I have to be able to grab just the text from html page (inside  tag) without the html tags.

For this, I'm trying to create a custom xsl template based on the default template: html2simplehtml.xsl.

Currently my import is working fine with html2simplehtml.xsl template.
here is example of the result node body from the import:

```
<div class="container-narrow">
<div class="masthead">
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
<li class="active">
<a href="/index.html">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/apps.html">Applications</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/middleware.html">Middleware</a>
</li>
```

now, the requirement is to only get:
    Home
    Applications
    Middleware

I have found this to remove html tags:

```
<!-- This will remove the tag -->
<xsl:template name="remove-html">
<xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-html">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&gt;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

but I am not sure where to put and how to call it using this:

```
<!-- Calling the template that removes tag -->
<xsl:call-template name="remove-html">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="{HtmlBody}"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with the way that Drupal calls your XSLT but let's assume it's a simple XSLT 1.0 processor using some HTML page as input and generating the output that you showed above. Let's further assume that the original HTML is well formed with all required closing tags, so that it's in fact XHTML which can be processed by the XSLT processor. (This is not true for the HTML you included in your question, by the way.)

So what you want to do is basically prevent all tags in the XML/XHTML input from showing up in the output. I think the easiest way to achieve this to use the `<xsl:value-of select>` tag. Assuming that you copy all the child tags of the `<body></body>` section of your XHTML like this:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*">
</xsl:template>
```

instead you could do this:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:value-of select=".">
</xsl:template>
```

`<xsl:value-of>` forces the evaluation of the XML sub tree into a string which is done (simply put) by concatenating all contained text elements. This does not, however, take care of white space yet. If you want to the eliminate disturbing white space you could brace the call like this:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)">
</xsl:template>
```

*Now for the template you originally wanted to use:* This does in fact remove tags from the input, too. But if I interpret the code right the input is *NOT* an XML node set but it must already be a *STRING*. So this works for other context in which you have a literal XML representation in a string. If you tried to use it here you would have to explicitly convert your XML representation into a string *beforehand* by using e.g. `<xsl:value-of>`. In this case the template would already be stripped off the tags (as described above) and would effectively not do anything at all but return the same string that it was passed as parameter. So IMHO, you will not need this template at all.